# Why is this double integral wrong?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

[This is the problem with the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyS4q.png)

[This is my attempt at solving it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9zuD.png)

Evidently, my attempt is wrong as the right answer is $36 \pi$. Why are my bounds wrong?

Edit tried to use math jax:
$$
\oint_C \left(3y-e^{\sin x}\right)\, dx + \left(7x+\sqrt{y^4+1}\right) \ dy
$$

I did this:
$$
\int_{-3}^3 \int_{-3}^{\sqrt{9-y^2}}\ \ 4 \ dx dy
$$

The correct answer is $36 \pi$ but this yields $18 \times (4+\pi)$. Why is it wrong?

Comment: Please don't put images. Look at the help of the website about writing maths.

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: Your lower bound on $x$ is constant when it should be parametrizing a semicircle, just like the upper bound. So, if one semicircle is $x = \sqrt{9-y^2}$, the other should be what?

Comment: @Ennar       -sqrt(9-y^2)?

Comment: Correct. If you check it with your calculator, indeed you'll get $36\pi$.

Comment: OHHHH ok thanks! @Ennar

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your integral is ok, and you need no calculator... You are integrating a constant function, so your integral is that constant multiplied by the area of the region, i.e., $4 \times (\pi \cdot 3^2) = 36 \pi$.